# Компоновка с бинарным файлом ELF

Tags: linux, компоновщик, elf, ld

Есть ли возможность скомпоновать программу с бинарным файлом и как это сделать?

В моем случае есть исполняемый бинарный ELF файл /bin/btrfs (интерфейс для администрирования файловой системы). Из него "торчат" несколько нужных мне символов-функций, по крайней мере так говорит `readelf -s`.

Могу ли я скомпоновать свою программу с этими функциями, не собирая их из исходников, а используя уже существующий в системе бинарный файл?

Comment: Файл должен быть собран с экспортированием символов и другой всякой мелочи, необходимой для динамического загрузчика. Разве btrfs не предоставляет библиотеки?

Answer (score 1):

Раньше вроде можно было передавать бинарник в dlopen, но начиная с какой-то версии нельзя, есть всякие python-скрипты, которые позволяют конвертнуть бинарник в shared object но надо будет его патчить

Если кратко, сейчас так нельзя

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67354859/is-it-possible-to-dlopen-an-executable-binary